# XSLT (XML to XML) needed to use computed max value

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there an XSLT that can transform 'XML Document 1' to 'XML Document 2' as shown below? In 'XML Document 1' I need to determine the *EncounterId* value where *EncounterDt* is the maximum value and then determine which Diagnoses have that *EncounterId* value. I can do each step separately but can't put them both together in a single transform. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

XML Document 1

```
<Data>
  <Encounters>
    <Encounter>
      <EncounterId>1234</EncounterId>
      <EncounterDt>01/01/2018</EncounterDt>
    </Encounter>
    <Encounter>
      <EncounterId>5678</EncounterId>
      <EncounterDt>01/02/2018</EncounterDt>
    </Encounter>
  </Encounters>
  <Diagnoses>
    <Diagnosis>
      <EncounterId>1234</EncounterId>
      <Code>ABCD</Code>
    </Diagnosis>
    <Diagnosis>
      <EncounterId>5678</EncounterId>
      <Code>EFGH</Code>
    </Diagnosis>
  </Diagnoses>
</Data>
```

Maximum *EncounterDt* from above is '01/02/2018' so we are interested in 
*Diagnoses* with `EncounterId = 5678`.

XML Document 2

```
<Data>
  <Encounters>
    <Encounter>
      <EncounterId>5678</EncounterId>
      <EncounterDt>01/02/2018</EncounterDt>
    </Encounter>
  </Encounters>
  <Diagnoses>
    <Diagnosis>
      <EncounterId>5678</EncounterId>
      <Code>EFGH</Code>
    </Diagnosis>
  </Diagnoses>
</Data>
```

Comment: Please show your two steps. Are these two separate documents or one? Look into `document()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 'XML Document 1' is the input document and 'XML Document 2' is the output of the transformation.

Comment: Your question: is it possible? Yes, it is possible. Give it a try and return when you have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by having a variable containing the `EncounterId` from the maximum `EncounterDt` as:

```
<xsl:variable name="kMaxEncounter">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Data/Encounters/Encounter">
        <!-- sorting the values by descending order
             to get the max value in the first position -->
        <xsl:sort select="EncounterDt" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
        <!-- get the value of the EncounterId -->
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="EncounterId"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

next is to have a do nothing templates that do not match the $kMaxEncounter

```
<xsl:template match="Encounter[EncounterId!=$kMaxEncounter]|
    Diagnosis[EncounterId!=$kMaxEncounter]"/>
```

and an identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See it in action (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Ca).